# Invalid Syntax on variables in python

Tags: python, syntax

May I know why there be a invalid syntax on my f variable on the first elif loop?

```
def bsd():
if price_of_properties <= 180000:
    price = 180000*0.1
    f = '{0:.2f}'.format(price)
    print("BSD is $" + str(f))
elif price_of_properties > 180000 <= 360000:
    price = (((180000*0.1) + (price_of_properties - 180000 + (180000* 0.2)))
    f = '{0:.2f}'.format(price)
    print("BSD is $" + str(f))
elif price_of_properties > 360000 <= 100000:
    price = (((180000*0.1) + (180000*0.2) +(price_of_properties - 180000 + (640000* 0.3)))
    f = '{0:.2f}'.format(price)
    print("BSD is $" + str(f))
```

Comment: Also you need to indent averything after the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second and third assignments to  the price variable have unbalaned parentheses ((more opens than closes).

This will cause an error on the following lines though I *think* Python 3.11 may fix that, reporting errors more accurately. You can probably fix this by adding a closing parenthesis on each of those two lines. Or removing the first. But check the formulae after you do so, in case you make the wrong choice.

And, yes, the extra opening parenthesis in that first paragraph was intended :-)